# How do I override (or overwrite?) a built-in Javascript function

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

For unit-testing purposes, I need to overwrite the `Number.prototype.toLocaleString()` so that it is always called with `en-US` rather than default behavior. I understand overwriting a normal built-in function that receives a parameter, but `toLocaleString()` does not take the Number to convert to string directly as parameter so I am confused here.

I tried the following:

```
Number.prototype.toLocaleStringTest = Number.prototype.toLocaleString
Number.prototype.toLocaleString = function() { this.toLocaleStringTest('en-US') }
```

But the result of this new `toLocaleString()` function is always `undefined`. New function is certainly called, by the way, I ensured this via adding a temporary `console.log("I am called!")` in the implementation.

What am I doing wrong -- Or am I trying to achieve something that is not doable?

Comment: Does `function() { return this.toLocaleStringTest('en-US') }` work?

Comment: I think the suggestion in @holydragon comment is correct... See my answer code snippet...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were very close... Only a `return` was missing... :-)

```js
Number.prototype.toLocaleStringTest = Number.prototype.toLocaleString
Number.prototype.toLocaleString = function() {
  return this.toLocaleStringTest('en-US')
}
n = 123456.789;
console.log(n.toLocaleString());
```